# How to show the names of multiple files in js

Tags: javascript, file, input

The Following code outputs only the **count** of files selected.

On Selecting **only one** file,it shows the name of file, but the same won't works on selecting **multiple files**.

```js
$('input').on('change', function(){
    if(this.files.length > 0)
    {
        $('div').text(this.files);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
Select a file to upload:
<input type="file" multiple/>
<div></div>
```

Comment: @epascarello is asking a good question here. The variable name "names" suggest plurality. Sure you haven't misspelled name, or that you might be trying to set an array as a text? What does the console say?

Comment: this.files is a array of files (FileList), in each file has your information, try print in console the this.files for you see.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('input').on('change', function(){
    if(this.files.length > 0)
    {
        var files = [];
        for(var i=0; i<this.files.length; i++) {
            files.push(this.files[i].name);
        }
        $('div').text(files);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
Select a file to upload:
<input type="file" multiple/>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The files is a FileList which is array like. There is no way to get all the names from a property. So with your example, if you changed names to name, you would get the first file name.

Getting only one name:

```js
$('input').on('change', function(){
    var out = "";
    if(this.files.length > 0)
    {
        out = this.files[0].name;
    }
    $('div').text(out);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
Select a file to upload:
<input type="file" multiple/>
<div></div>
```

Getting all the names, you need to loop over the collection and build the string.

```js
$('input').on('change', function(){
    var out = "";
    if(this.files.length > 0)
    {
        out = [].slice.call(this.files).map(function(f) { return f.name; }).join(", ");
    }
    $('div').text(out);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
Select a file to upload:
<input type="file" multiple/>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the `FileList` object that contains all selected files. Each `File` object has the following properties:

- name
- size
- type

These can be useful if you want make a kind of validation or something else.

```js
function handleFiles (files) {
 const output = document.getElementById('files');
  let outText = output.textContent;
  
  if (files.length) {
   outText = '';
  }

 [...Array(files.length)].forEach((v, i) => {
   const file = files.item(i);
    const filename = file.name;
    outText += `- ${filename}\n`;
  });
  output.textContent = outText;
}
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
input[type="file"] {
  display: none;
}
input[type="file"] + label {
  background-color: #ff0065;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'open sans';
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 20px 0 0 2rem;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
}

pre#files {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #444;
  font-family: 'open sans';
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="selector" multiple onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
<label for="selector">Select files</label>
<pre id="files">No files found</pre>
```